# Bank account application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a Bank account application that tracks deposits and withdrawals for a C# course.

The problem I'm having is, it looks like the account balance is being reset (or something).

When you enter a number and click the button, it's (supposedly) added to the balance and displayed in the textbox. Unfortunately, when you enter a number, the number itself is displayed in the textbox. I don't know why.

My code is below:

```
namespace Assign11
{
using System;

public class BankAccount
{
    private double inValue;
    private double accountBalance;

    public BankAccount()
    {
    }

    public BankAccount(double input)
    {
        inValue = input;
        Deposit();
    }

    public double Invalue
    {
        set
        {
            inValue = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return inValue;
        }
    }

    public double AccountBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return accountBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            accountBalance = value;
        }
    }

    public void Deposit()
    {
        accountBalance = accountBalance + inValue;
    }
  }
}
```

I've also got the following form:

```
namespace Assign11
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_deposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        double input;
        input = double.Parse((putin.Text));

        BankAccount anAccount = new BankAccount(input);

        output.Text = anAccount.AccountBalance.ToString();        
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because you instantiate a `BankAccount` object every time you click the button. That's why the AccountBalance will always start from zero and not add up.

Declare your `BankAccount` object in class scope so the balance will retain.
Change the `Deposit` function to accept the deposit amount and use that value in to be added in the account balance